Create multirows based on CSV content
I have the following Latex code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{csvsimple} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering 
\csvreader[tabular=@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lccccc, table head=\toprule & & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & Gap & Time \\\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\# Worker& 
Demand Pattern & LB & UB & & \\\midrule, late after line=\\, table foot=\bottomrule]{text.csv}{}{\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&\csvcolv&\csvcolvi} 
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}

This code creates a table based on the values from a .csv. The example CSV looks like this.
Nr, Demand, LB, UB, Gap, Time
100, High-Low,2,0.052,0.294,0.115
100,High-Medium,2,0.511,0.083,0.123
150,High-High,3,0.320,0.344,0.382
150,Low-High,3,0.378,0.296,0.123

How do I have to adapt the code so that if two or more values are the same in the first column "Nr", they are then made into a field, e.g. with the \multirow command. In this case, the two 100 values should be merged into one cell and the two 150 values. If there are three or more identical values among each other, then of course the same. How do I have to adapt the code for this?

This is tricky. I guess it can be programmed with enough effort. But do you realise that without horizontal lines it will be hard to see which rows belong to a block if two blocks are vertically adjacent and have differen numbers of rows in them? For example if you have 2 times 100 and 3 times 150, it is hard to see in one glimpse  if the separation is between row 2 and 3 or 3 and 4.

I'm not able to write a "LaTeX only" solution, but if you have the possibility to use Python, it is easy to solve your problem.
I added some rows to your .csv, just to show the \multirow number can change.
Starting from text.csv:
Nr, Demand, LB, UB, Gap, Time
100, High-Low,2,0.052,0.294,0.115
100,High-Medium,2,0.511,0.083,0.123
150,High-High,3,0.320,0.344,0.382
150,Low-High,3,0.378,0.296,0.123
200,Low-High,4,0.390,0.297,0.127
200,High-Medium,4,0.392,0.396,0.173
200,High-High,4,0.400,0.276,0.723

you can write a simple Python program:
# Import of the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the current csv
testo = pd.read_csv("text.csv")

# Leave out blanks in headers:
testo.columns =[col.strip() for col in testo.columns]

# Count of equal values in Nr 
testo['freq'] = testo.groupby('Nr')['Nr'].transform('count')

# Create \multirow string
testo['Multi'] = np.where(testo['Nr'].shift() == testo['Nr'], '', "\multirow[t]{"+testo['freq'].astype(str)+"}{*}{"+testo['Nr'].astype(str)+"}")

# Write output csv
testo.reindex(columns=["Multi","Demand","LB","UB","Gap","Time"])\
    .to_csv("newtext.csv",index=False)

that produces newtext.csv (I put the [t] in the \multicolumn to have it in the first line, you can change it, of course):
Multi,Demand,LB,UB,Gap,Time
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{100}, High-Low,2,0.052,0.294,0.115
,High-Medium,2,0.511,0.083,0.123
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{150},High-High,3,0.32,0.344,0.382
,Low-High,3,0.378,0.296,0.123
\multirow[t]{3}{*}{200},Low-High,4,0.39,0.297,0.127
,High-Medium,4,0.392,0.396,0.173
,High-High,4,0.4,0.276,0.723

and then use newtext.csv in your LaTeX code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{csvsimple} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering 
\csvreader[tabular=@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lccccc, table head=\toprule & & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & Gap & Time \\\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\# Worker& 
Demand Pattern & LB & UB & & \\\midrule, late after line=\\, table foot=\bottomrule]{newtext.csv}{}{\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&\csvcolv&\csvcolvi} 
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}

with this result:

You can also write the table in Python directly (with a little hack suggested by samcarter.
This way you don't need csvsimple anymore.
This Python code:
# Import of the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the current csv
testo = pd.read_csv("text.csv")

# Leave out blanks in headers:
testo.columns =[col.strip() for col in testo.columns]

# Count of equal values in Nr 
testo['freq'] = testo.groupby('Nr')['Nr'].transform('count')

# Create \multirow string
testo['Multi'] = np.where(testo['Nr'].shift() == testo['Nr'], '', "\multirow[t]{"+testo['freq'].astype(str)+"}{*}{"+testo['Nr'].astype(str)+"}")

# Write output .tex
#codeOK testo.reindex(columns=["Multi","Demand","LB","UB","Gap","Time"]).style\
#codeOK     .hide(axis="index").format(precision=3).\
#codeOK         to_latex("mytable.tex",hrules=True,siunitx=True)
newtesto=testo.reindex(columns=["Multi","Demand","LB","UB","Gap","Time"])
#print(newtesto)
columns = [
    ('','\# Workers'),
    ('','Demand pattern'),
    ('Bounds','LB'),
    ('Bounds','UB'),   
    ('Gap',''),   
    ('Time','')
]
newtesto.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
newtesto.head()
latex = newtesto.style.hide(axis="index").format(precision=3).\
    to_latex(hrules=True,multicol_align='c',column_format='@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lccccc')

latex_list = latex.splitlines()
latex_list.insert(3, '\\cmidrule(lr){3-4}')

latex_new = '\n'.join(latex_list)

print(latex_new, file=open('mytable.tex', 'w'))

produces mytable.tex:
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & Gap & Time \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\# Workers & Demand pattern & LB & UB &  &  \\
\midrule
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{100} &  High-Low & 2 & 0.052 & 0.294 & 0.115 \\
 & High-Medium & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 \\
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{150} & High-High & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 \\
 & Low-High & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 \\
\multirow[t]{3}{*}{200} & Low-High & 4 & 0.390 & 0.297 & 0.127 \\
 & High-Medium & 4 & 0.392 & 0.396 & 0.173 \\
 & High-High & 4 & 0.400 & 0.276 & 0.723 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

that you can \input directly in your LaTeX code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering 
\input{mytable.tex}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}

with this result:

P.S. = I am a newbie in Pyhton, maybe there are even simpler methods than the ones I showed you.
